Счетчик для цикла while
Вопрос такой: нормально ли делать счётчики с переменными, где число мы записываем из пользовательского ввода?
n = int(input())

while n!= 0:
    print("hi")
    n-=1


А что может помешать? Циклу while нужно логическое условие. Каково происхождение переменных в этом условии - его не волнует.

MBo, я просто подумал, что может это как-то не особо хорошо где-то на более внутреннем уровне

В while нет никаких внутренних ограничений, он простой как топор. Но в целом циклы со счетчиком логично делать через for с range - как минимум не нужно будет вручную менять переменную счетчика.

Ну вы, конечно, можете для счётчика использовать другую переменную и сравнивать её с той переменной, которая введена через input. Но зачем делать лишнюю переменную, если можно обойтись одной - той, которая была введена через input? )  В принципе, может быть такой случай, когда вам нужно зачем-то сохранить значение, введённое через input - вот тогда вам в любом случае нужна будет вторая переменная.

Чтобы было удобнее делать счётчики можно использовать for x in range(y)
Например:
x = int(input())

for i in range(x): # Если х = 10, то "hi" будет выведено 10 раз
    print("hi")

А также i (или любую другую переменную (x, y, test, word, ksnjvckj и т.д.)) можно использовать для того, чтобы узнать какой раз выполняется цикл, например:
for x in range(5):
    print(x)

Вывод:
0 #Отсчёт начинается с 0, а не 1
1
2
3
4

